How can I prevent TMPro fonts from automatically modifying while project building?
When I go to file > build and run (or build), the TMPro .asset files changes automatically. Don't want to go around stashing the changes everytime I build my project. This happens when the dialog for the building appears.
I built the project and I was expecting nothing would change.

I cant say ive ever seen this

Is this about programming? It sounds like it's just about Unity game engine use rather than programming using C# or Unity Script? If that's the case, please ask on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ instead--that site is for general game development questions (including programming ones, if you wish), whereas this site is specifically/exclusively for programming questions.
